# Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) from Mac Appstore ot warning Error in console When running blank project?

Tags: xcode, warnings, message

Summary:

```
New project - First only running in consola Warning this:
2016-09-16 15:50:07.931684 pop-up-Reading[52256:421889] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-16 15:50:07.937492 pop-up-Reading[52256:421889] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-16 15:50:07.954866 pop-up-Reading[52256:421870] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-16 15:50:07.979466 pop-up-Reading[52256:421658] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-16 15:50:08.025295 pop-up-Reading[52256:421658] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
```

Try:

```
Product Scheme/ Edit Scheme -> Arguments

Environment Variables ->      OS_ACTIVITY_MODE     disable
```

After close Xcode 8 and restar and no work solution without this warning

Answer (score 1):

Edit scheme() and under Run --> Arguments --> Environment variables. Add a new environment variable OS_ACTIVITY_MODE with value disable. Clean, build and run. Error will be disabled.